# define \label and \ref with shortcuts

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion

Is there a way define \label and \pageref with shortcuts depending of context.

In the mwe neither work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\phasevie[2]{\section{#1-#2}\def\cod{#2}}
\newcommand\reffs[1]{\fctcod-#1}
\newcommand\reffc[1]{\fctcod-#1~page~\pageref{fct:\fctcod{}-#1}}
\newenvironment{FC}[2]{\def\fctcod{\cod{}FC#2}}{}
\newenvironment{FIC}[3]
{%
    \def\fctcod{\cod{}FC#2-#3}
    \subsection{\fctcod{} --- #1}\label{fct:\fctcod{}}
}{}

\begin{document}
\phasevie{phase1}{PHS}
\begin{FC}{This is a function}{1}
criteria number one explained inline: \reffs{1}

criteria number two explained after: \reffc{2}

criteria number two explained after: \reffs{2}~page~\pageref{fct:PHSFC1-2}
\end{FC}

\begin{FIC}{Criteria}{1}{2}
%    \label{fct:PHSFC1-2}
Description of function criteria \fctcod{}.
\end{FIC}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use braces everywhere. Inside label and ref they can matter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\cod{}
\newcommand\fctcod{}
\newcommand\phasevie[2]{\section{#1-#2}\def\cod{#2}}

\newcommand\reffs[1]{\fctcod-#1}
\newcommand\reffc[1]{\fctcod-#1~page~\pageref{fct:\fctcod-#1}}
\newenvironment{FC}[2]{\def\fctcod{\cod FC#2}}{}
\newenvironment{FIC}[3]
{%
    \def\fctcod{\cod FC#2-#3}
    \subsection{\fctcod{} --- #1}\label{fct:\fctcod}
}{}

\begin{document}
\phasevie{phase1}{PHS}
\begin{FC}{This is a function}{1}
criteria number one explained inline: \reffs{1}

criteria number two explained after: \reffc{2}

criteria number two explained after: \reffs{2}~page~\pageref{fct:PHSFC1-2}
\end{FC}

\begin{FIC}{Criteria}{1}{2}
%    \label{fct:PHSFC1-2}
Description of function criteria \fctcod{}.
\end{FIC}
\end{document}
```